# Horizontol scrollbar in android text view

Tags: android, scroll

I have a expandable list view consisting of varied sized textviews. The TextView size depends upon the contents in it. Now there are certain text which exceeds the screen width and the user is not able to view it.

I have tried HorizontolScrollView inside a ScrollView. It performs the scrolling but as my UI is a bit complex, it doesnot renders the other widgets in the view (like checkbox) properly.

Please suggest some good ideas to do the manual text scrolling.

Marquee is not a good suggestion. :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nested scroll view is a big 'no no' in android as there is no good way to determine which scroll has focus.

My solution would be to make an non-editable EditText.  I would do something like this.

```
<EditText android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:editable="false" 
android:enabled="false"  
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/editText1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
```

TextView seems to have a android:scrollHorizontally property as well but I have had no luck getting it to function.

Comment: I used the below code for the textview: <TextView android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="24dp" android:maxLines="1" android:text="Text" android:layout_height="40dp" android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:padding="4dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/demo_list_item_description"> </TextView>. But I have no luck with this one.

Comment: like I don't think scrolling works in a textview even though it has the attribute.  You can make EditText look very pleasant for displaying text.